# How to play an encrypted media file-IOS-iPhone?

Tags: ios, encryption, media

i'm writing an app to play some media encrypted files
Normally,we can decrypt these files and play it.But i don't want anybody can get this decrypt file when app is playing this file.
Or i want protect these file.
I'm researching but i don't find a solution.
Can anyone suggest to me a solution?Can anyway to protect media files without encryption?
Thanks so much.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The short answer:  You can't stop copying, no matter how hard you try.

The long answer:  This problem has been around since the dawn of Internet distribution.  Nobody has solved it effectively yet.  The problem is that if a user jailbreaks a device they can do anything that the hardware is capable of.  This includes recording directly from the audio buffer into a file, making it a simple process to capture your file while it is playing and dump the contents into another file.  Therefore, if you can play it, you can copy it.  The only solution that I can see working is to build your own hardware that doesn't allow external access to the audio buffer, but that is impossible for 99% of people and impractical for 100%.

The compromise:  The best you can do is make it more trouble than it is worth for the user.  If you can decrypt into a memory buffer then it will be an annoying task to get the data, and most people will probably not put the effort into it.